# Google Spreadsheet Timestamp?

Tags: google-sheets, google-apps-script, google-sheets-timestamp

I'm looking for some help with my Daily Work Log spreadsheet.
I've search and read many different version of making a "TimeStamp" in Google spreadsheet.
And it seems I don't have enough experience for it to work correctly. The time stamp script I am using updates every time my spreadsheet auto saves or something is changed.

Here's what I'm tring to do. I have work force of technicians. 
Initials are AB, DD, RG, JW, RZ.

I want the spreadsheet to time stamp column N when they enter their initials in column M.

I know you can use the keyboard shortcut <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>:</kbd> to time stamp a cell.
Is there a script I can use to do that action in column N when initials are entered in 
column M?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11458470/automatic-timestamp-when-a-cell-is-filled-out) from StackOverflow:

Here's the relevant code (*edited*):

```
function onEdit() {
 var s = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
 if( s.getName() == "Sheet1" ) { //checks that we're on the correct sheet
   var r = s.getActiveCell();
   if( r.getColumn() == 13 ) { //checks the column
     var nextCell = r.offset(0, 1);
     if( nextCell.getValue() === '' ) //is empty?
       var time = new Date();
       time = Utilities.formatDate(time, "GMT", "HH:mm:ss");
       nextCell.setValue(time);
   };
 };
}
```

Comment: This is great. So I have created a new script and copy / pasted this code. I have changed ( r.getColumn() == 4) to (r.getColumn() == 13) for when column M is edited column N will be stamped with the date. Tried it out and doesn't work. Also I will have to change nextCell.setValue(new Date()); to Time stamp the Current Time instead of current Date.

Comment: @myanda - I updated my code to account for your use case. Try that and see if it works.

Comment: Hmmm, entered this new script in my google spreadsheet. Still not working. Any ideas?

Comment: Is your sheet named "Sheet1"? If not, did you change the third line in the code to use your sheet name?

Comment: I just thought of that, just changed the name and tried it. Still doesn't work. Its closing time at the work here. I'll be home shortly to work on it more.

Comment: Alright back to another day at the office. I have renamed my spreadsheet to Sheet1. Spreadsheet is still not working.

Comment: Not sure what the problem is, the code is working for me. Try grabbing my code again, I added some semi-colons, though shouldn't have affected the outcome?

Comment: Odd.. I just created a new spreadsheet. Titled it Sheet1, copy/pasted your code again. and it works.

Comment: Deleted all the code in my Daily Work Log sheet. Its named Sheet1. Still doesn't work. Very odd. I wonder if the problem has to do with rows that i have merged?

Comment: Could be? I'm not sure about that piece though. Good to hear it works on a blank sheet - good luck with the other sheet, hopefully it just needs some tweaking

Comment: Thank you very much for your help. Hopefully i can find what the problem is.

Comment: VICTORY !!! I got it working. I was making the noob error of mistaking "Speardsheet Name" as the "Sheet Name".

Comment: Here's the next problem I have. In the if( s.getName() == "Sheet1" ) statment. Is there a way to have this code work with a range of 31 sheets? I'm renaming the sheets as the current date 10-9-12.

Comment: If you remove the if statement then the script should work on the 13th column in every sheet, regardless of title. As long as the format in each sheet is the same, the 14th column will always get timestamped when the 13th is edited.

Comment: Got it to work. Thanks again for all your help.