# How can I automatically set "last updated" cell in row Google Docs Spreadsheets?

Tags: google-sheets, google-apps-script, google-sheets-timestamp

How can I automatically set "last updated" cell in row Google Docs Spreadsheets ?

I want to create a column where the cells' value will be automatically set to when that row was last amended. Is this possible? How do I do this / what option do I use to set this?

I see a [workaround for MS Excel](http://www.eggheadcafe.com/community/excel/66/10075090/row-modification-date.aspx) but I think Google Docs should have something similar, right? (fingers crossed)

We have multiple people editing a large sheet. We can see revision history, but it would be nicer if we had a column of "last updated" dates as well.

Comment: Have you tried? If it work, then please mark as such, see http://webapps.stackexchange.com/faq#howtoask.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

You can try adding a Google Apps Script to capture when a cell is edited and add a timestamp to a different cell. Here's a previous answer that is similar:
[Google Spreadsheet Timestamp?](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/31894/google-spreadsheet-timestamp/31942#31942)

```
function onEdit() {
 var s = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
 if( s.getName() == "Sheet1" ) { //checks that we're on the correct sheet
   var r = s.getActiveCell();
   if( r.getColumn() == 13 ) { //checks the column
     var nextCell = r.offset(0, 1);
     if( nextCell.getValue() === '' ) //is empty?
       var time = new Date();
       time = Utilities.formatDate(time, "GMT", "HH:mm:ss");
       nextCell.setValue(time);
   };
 };
}
```

Comment: Please try my answer to [Google Sheets HTML Service Sidebar to run code as owner](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28756787/google-sheets-html-service-sidebar-to-run-code-as-owner/35422216#35422216)

Answer (score 59):

`=iferror(A1+B1+C1+D1+J1+K1+L1+"x",today())` whenever the cells in the row changes the formula re-calculates. with the "x" in the equation it guarantees an error. which in return, returns the date.

Comment: That's an interesting kluge.

Comment: The most beautiful solution I've ever seen :)

Comment: As far as I can tell, this doesn't actually work.  To be clear, it works, but it's not updated for specific rows.  When I put this in and drag it through multiple rows, then edit anything anywhere on the sheet, all of the rows are recalculated and updated.

Comment: Wow!  It worked for me.  Here is a shortened version:
=iferror(SUM(A2:O2)+"x",today())
and dragging it automatically updated row numbers.

Comment: Ya, it updates all rows with same value regardless of cells in iferror.

Comment: This doesn't seem to work for me: the formula is reevaluated whenever the spreadsheet is refreshed.

Comment: Use NOW() instead of TODAY() in case you need granularity to the second.

Comment: This Epic solution, there are hacks then there are legendary hacks, this is one of legendary hacks! Good job!

Comment: CAUTION!!  This updates each time you change ANYTHING in the sheet. Does not actually achieve what you're looking for

Comment: +1 wish it were true, but this is pretty much useless except to put in a single cell to mark the last time the sheet was updated.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a version that finds the column using the header, rather than hardcoding the column number, and uses a custom time zone:

```
function updateModified(options) {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  if (options.sheetName && sheet.getName() != options.sheetName) {
    return;
  }

  var modifiedColumnName = options.modifiedColumnName || 'Modified';
  var header = sheet.getDataRange().offset(0, 0, 1).getValues()[0];
  var modifiedColumn;
  for (var i=0; i < header.length; i++) {
    if (header[i].trim() == modifiedColumnName) {
      modifiedColumn = i + 1;
      break;
    }
  }
  if (typeof modifiedColumn != 'number') {
    throw new Error("Can't find column with name: " + modifiedColumnName);
  }

  var activeCell = sheet.getActiveCell();
  if (activeCell.getColumn() == modifiedColumn) {
    return;
  }

  var modifiedCell = sheet.getRange(activeCell.getRow(), modifiedColumn);
  var formattedDate = Utilities.formatDate(new Date(), "America/Los_Angeles", "M/dd/yy HH:mm");
  modifiedCell.setValue(formattedDate);
}

function onEdit() {
  updateModified({sheetName: 'Jobs'});
}
```

To use UTC, just change the time zone to UTC.

Comment: This was almost perfect for what I needed, thank you! I modified it a bit to make it more dynamic: https://gist.github.com/kodie/6dd1e4cb3cfd70a429d79c751bc8fb42

Answer (score 1):

This is my script, put in the last column this information:

1. Insert into the Cell (in the last cell = lastcolumn for the row that you modify) - Date in GMT -3, if you want to put the same in other TZ just modify the -3 for you concurrent timezone. If you want to put the date automatically in your default TZ, just modify this:

   ```
   var date = Utilities.formatDate(new Date(), "GMT-3", "dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm");
   to
   var date = Utilities.formatDate(new Date());
   ```
2. Insert a Comment with the Cell+User who modify it.
3. Appear a popup when you update something. Only appear to the ActiveUser.

   ```
   function onEdit(event)
   {
       var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
       var actSht = event.source.getActiveSheet();
       var actRng = event.source.getActiveRange();

       var index = actRng.getRowIndex();
       var dateCol = actSht.getLastColumn();
       var lastCell = actSht.getRange(index,dateCol);
       var date = Utilities.formatDate(new Date(), "GMT-3", "dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm");

       lastCell.setValue(date);
       lastCell.setComment("Ultima Modificacion: " + actRng.getA1Notation() +' por '+Session.getActiveUser());
       ss.toast('Ultima Modificacion = '+ actRng.getA1Notation()+' por '+Session.getActiveUser());
   }
   ```

Answer (score 1):

I've created a function that write a new Date when the referenced cell is modified. In this case the cell value is TRUE or FALSE but you can edit it to any value.

```
function WhenUpdated(cell1) {
  if(cell1){
    return new Date();
  }
  else return null;
}
```

Answer (score -3):

Simply type "Last updated:" in one cell and type "=now()" in the cell next to it! That should do the job!

Comment: This will only work per-cell, not per row as stated in the question

Comment: I _so_ want to +1 this answer 