# I Need a script or a formula to get Logged User Name in Column C When he enter the cell from drop down list Selection in Column D In Google Sheet

Tags: google-sheets, google-apps-script, formulas

I Need the Logged User Name in Column  C  When he enter the cell from drop down list Selection in Column D In Google Sheet
I have number of users to use one sheet they Have a list of drop down selection in Column D When they fill the column one by one I should get the logged user name in Column C one by one.

In Column D3 D4 and D5 ...... if he select the cell value I should get his name in Column C3 C4 and C5 ......
Hope some one will help me out

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is there any way to identify a user in Google Apps Script?](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/106379/is-there-any-way-to-identify-a-user-in-google-apps-script)

Comment: It's not possible to get the logged user using formulas.

Answer (score -2):

Its simple, no need to complicate things with codes & formulas just Create a Form & from the form settings set the form to Collect the Users email address everytime the form is submitted- you just need to collate the data of eeach user the first time to link each users name to their email addresses incase they using personal email addresses-put the drop down list on the form not on the sheet.

The Form Response sheet will have all the data you need once the users submits the form.