# "Last Modified" function

Tags: google-sheets

I have a problem in using Google Sheets. My sheet is shared with others so I want to add a "Last Modified" function in each row, so I can know when it was last modified.

I've searched Google for a solution but most are using scripts, and I don't know how to use scripts. I made a sheet, in which I just want a particular cell in a column to input the date and time whenever any cell in the same row is updated.

Comment: I don't think this is possible without using scripts, but it's quite easy to add a script like this. Check this soution: http://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/37415/29712

Answer (score 1):

## Short answer

There is no built-in function to do what you ask. If you don't want to use a script, the alternative is to use an add-on.

## Extended answer

The related built-in functions are NOW() and TODAY() but they recalculate automatically. The only way to freeze them automatically is by using a script, to make things easier for end users developers could publish add-ons.

At this time I don't know of an add-on that does what you are looking for. Try to find one by yourself.

An alternative is to use a spreadsheet template that already has the script. The old template gallery have at least one, [ubersimple AutoTimeStamp](https://drive.google.com/previewtemplate?id=0AjaqQnCvakzUdDRBOXFLS3F5Nmxza2VwUGI2YjhUNGc&mode=public). I tried it some time ago, but I'm not sure that it's still working.

Note: The old template gallery will not be available later in 2016.

## References

- [Google spreadsheets function list](https://support.google.com/docs/table/25273?hl=en)
- [Use add-ons & Apps Script](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/2942256?hl=en)
- [Docs, Sheets, and Slides templates](https://support.google.com/drive/answer/148833?hl=en)