# Auto-updating column in Google Spreadsheet in a specific sheet

Tags: google-sheets

I'm using a function that I found on another [thread](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/37408/auto-updating-column-in-google-spreadsheet-showing-last-modify-date?newreg=e725abb4fbfd41abb5b2285190843842) here on stackexchange, but I would like to limit the function to only work in 1 specific sheet at the time.

I have old sheets with history that is overwritten if there is a change in those sheets.

The function I use:

```
function onEdit() {
  var s = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var r = s.getActiveCell();
  if( r.getColumn() != 2 ) { //checks the column
    var row = r.getRow();
    var time = new Date();
    time = Utilities.formatDate(time, "GMT+02:00", "dd.MM.yyyy, HH:mm");
    SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange('T' + row.toString()).setValue(time);
  };
 };
```

I'm guessing I have to add the name of the sheet within getRange?

Answer (score 1):

Found it out myself for those needing help.

Use getSheetByName(Name)

```
function onEdit() {
  var s = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('UPDATE');
  var r = s.getActiveCell();
  if( r.getColumn() != 2 ) { //checks the column
    var row = r.getRow();
    var time = new Date();
    time = Utilities.formatDate(time, "GMT+02:00", "dd.MM.yyyy, HH:mm");
    SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('UPDATE').getRange('T' + row.toString()).setValue(time);
  };
 };
```