# Google Script: Changing date format from Typeform Response in Sheets

Tags: google-sheets, google-apps-script, google-docs

I'm using Google Script to add a function where once the response from Typeform is sent to the sheet, a button called "create document" is added to fill up the Google Doc template using the **body.replacetext** script function.

Apparently I want the document to have a specific name auto generated which was possible with the function:

```
const copy = googleDocTemplate.makeCopy(`HR-4R-${row[2]}-${row[1]}-${(row[15]).toLocaleDateString()} `, destinationFolder)
```

- where row 2 in sheet is: code
- where row 1 in sheet is: position
- where row 15 in sheet is date submitted (generated by typeform based on the date form was completed)

The ideal name for each document will be: **HR-4R-AZM-VIDEO EDITOR-01-15-2021**. My problem is using the .toLocaleDateString it formats the date into MM/DD/YYYY and I can't format it into MM-DD-YYYY. Another issue I'm having is Typeform exports response in UTC which conflicts the date of submission.

Is there a way to format the date into MM-DD-YYYY and change the time zone based on the location I am in?

Answer (score 0):

From the question

> Is there a way to format the date into MM-DD-YYYY and change the time zone based on the location I am in?

Server side runs on Google servers, so JavaScript methods like `toLocaleDateString()` use the Google servers locale instead of the locale of the user.

Instead of `toLocaleDateString()` you could use `Utilities.formatDate(date, timezone, format)`

```
var timezone = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSpreadsheetTimezone();// This will return the time zone set in the spreadsheet, by default it gets the spreadsheet creator time zone.
var date = Utilities.formatDate(row[15], timezone, 'MM-dd-yyyy');
const copy = googleDocTemplate.makeCopy(`HR-4R-${row[2]}-${row[1]}-${date} `, destinationFolder)
```

Related

- [Auto-updating column in Google Spreadsheet showing last modify date](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/37408/88163)

Reference

- https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/utilities/utilities#formatDate(Date,String,String)

Comment: Thanks for the help to both of you. It worked nicely!

Comment: @KristiansandSalazar Please checkout [What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://webapps.stackexchang.com/help/someone-answer)