# Need Help with Timestamp Function

Tags: google-sheets-timestamp

As entered, every time I check ANY box, ALL timestamps update. I'd like only the corresponding cell to provide a current timestamp. All others to remain as previously stamped.

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1LUuxgiGsyHxb5u-L8jUXeMYnGxHjxr_QTHc2iFW7FKw/edit#gid=1170018105

Comment: There's a [Google App Script](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/37408/197614) which updates specific timestamp cells based on a cell elsewhere in that row being modified. Does that work for you?